# realloc() deletes first element

Tags: c, return-value, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have this function:

```c
node* creaNodo(coordinata pos, node** known, int* nKnown){
    node* nodo = exists(known, pos, *nKnown);
    if(nodo == NULL){
        (*nKnown)++;
        realloc(known, (*nKnown) * sizeof(node*));
        nodo = malloc(sizeof(node) * 1);
        nodo->nNextNodes = 0;
        nodo->nextNodes = NULL;
        nodo->nPreviousNodes = 0;
        nodo->previousNodes = NULL;
        nodo->posizione = pos;
        known[*nKnown - 1] = nodo;
    } 
    return nodo;
}
```

It basically check if a node already exists in my array (known) and if it doesn't it add it to my array or, if it does, it return the existing node. I'm having this weird behavior with realloc where after some iteration of me calling the function the realloc lose the first element of my array setting its value to NULL (0x0). I checked this by running the code with gdb and adding to my watchlist known[0].
I tested it using this main:

```c
int main(){
    node** known = malloc(sizeof(node*) * 1);
    int nKnown = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        coordinata* tmp = assegnaCoordinata(i,i);
        creaNodo(*tmp, known, &nKnown);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of the call of realloc is not stored in any variable

```
realloc(known, (*nKnown) * sizeof(node*));
```

so such a call invokes undefined behavior if you will try to access the memory by the address stored in the variable `known`.

At least you need to write

```
known = realloc(known, (*nKnown) * sizeof(node*));
```

though it is better to use an intermediate variable because the function can return a null pointer as for example

```
node** tmp = realloc(known, (*nKnown) * sizeof(node*));

if ( tmp != NULL ) known = tmp;
//...
```

Comment: I tried editing the line like you said but i still get the same strange behavior as before.

Comment: @DaniloMaglia I described the problem in your function   creaNodo. I do not know what you are doing something else in your program.

Comment: I checked again with the debugger and it almost fixed. While i'm inside the function known[0] now doesn't lose it's original value after the call to realloc,, but now when i return to the main and check again known[0] it's value is again 0x0.

Comment: @DaniloMaglia Close the question selecting the best answer and ask a new question providing a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.